# Why did I lose 4 rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

I just saw this:

[image]

but there are no downvotes or anything:

[What's happening with FromDigits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752119/whats-happening-with-fromdigits)

[How to make a dictionary of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407195/how-to-make-a-dictionary-of-arrays)

Why?

Comment: The number you see next to the question itself is the **score**, which is the sum of upvotes and downvotes. Score of 0 might mean one upvote and one downvote, and that's what happened in your case. Bit confusing, but easy to detect via reputation tab. Numbers don't lie.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry, I didn't notice there was also an upvote. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your questions has received 1 upvote and 1 downvote so far. So the score that you see is 1-1 = 0. Note that you still came ahead in terms of reputation: each upvote on a question adds 5, each downvote subtracts 2.

Answer (score 4):

Your [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4414359/solarmew?tab=reputation) tab shows your received two downvotes. A down vote is -2 reputation.

```
2 x -2 = -4 reputation
```

Comment: Yep, I understand those were downvotes. I just saw the "0" votes on the actual post and since I couldn't remember them ever being upvoted, was wondering why it wasn't "-1".